# How to write progress code equivalent to encodeuricomponent of javascript?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, webspeed

I have a variable with data type longchar which holds the value:

```
val='DQoJICA8bGkgY2xhc3M9ImhvbWUiPjxhIGhyZWY9InkyeWdlbmVyYWx3b3JsZC5wP3dvcmxkPWdlbmVyYWwiPltsLXBmaG9tZV08L2E+ID4gPGEgaHJlZj0ieTJkYXNoYm9hcmQucD93b3JsZD1idWxsZXQiPkJ1bGxldCBbbC1ob21lXTwvYT48L2xpPiANCgkJICAgDQoJCSAgPCEtLSBbcHJldmxpbmstc3RhcnRdIC0tPjxsaSBjbGFzcz0iIiA+ID4gPGEgaHJlZj0iamF2YXNjcmlwdDp2b2lkKDApIiBvbkNsaWNrPSJyZXR1cm4gZmFsc2U7Ij5bbC1yZWNlbnRpdGVtXTwvYT48L2xpPjwhLS0gW3ByZXZsaW5rLXN0b3BdIC0tPg0KCQk='
```

I transfered this variable with page redirect.

```
run p-redirectto( 'mynextpage.p?value=' + val).
```

in mynextpage.p i get the value of variable val as:

```
val='DQoJICA8bGkgY2xhc3M9ImhvbWUiPjxhIGhyZWY9InkyeWdlbmVyYWx3b3JsZC5wP3dvcmxkPWdlbmVyYWwiPltsLXBmaG9tZV08L2E ID4gPGEgaHJlZj0ieTJkYXNoYm9hcmQucD93b3JsZD1idWxsZXQiPkJ1bGxldCBbbC1ob21lXTwvYT48L2xpPiANCgkJICAgDQoJCSAgPCEtLSBbcHJldmxpbmstc3RhcnRdIC0tPjxsaSBjbGFzcz0iIiA ID4gPGEgaHJlZj0iamF2YXNjcmlwdDp2b2lkKDApIiBvbkNsaWNrPSJyZXR1cm4gZmFsc2U7Ij5bbC1yZWNlbnRpdGVtXTwvYT48L2xpPjwhLS0gW3ByZXZsaW5rLXN0b3BdIC0tPg0KCQk'
```

My problem is I want the value stored in val in mynextpage.p exactly it was before i redirect to this page.

how am i supposed to do this?

Comment: Help me out here... what's the difference?  They look identical to my eyes.

Comment: There is a difference. '+' and '=' are missing in received variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming webspeed there is a URL-ENCODE( ) method.